# Is there a wget command for Solaris 10

Tags: download, wget, solaris-10

Solaris 11 has wget command, like Linux's.

Is there wget or wget like command for Solaris 10?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The wget command in Solaris 10 is somewhat hidden from sight.

You can find it here

`/usr/sfw/bin/wget`

This was checked on s10u10

Comment: I think if you do `ln -s /usr/sfw/bin/wget /usr/bin/wget` it would be much easier - then just write to terminal `wget ...`

Answer (score 2):

My Solaris system has it installed, but I do not control the image we use to install it.  I see this:

```
$ which wget                                                                 
/usr/sfw/bin/wget

$ wget --version                                                             
GNU Wget 1.12 built on solaris2.10.

$ pkginfo -l SUNWwgetr                                                       
   PKGINST:  SUNWwgetr
      NAME:  GNU wget - utility to retrieve files from the World Wide Web (root)
  CATEGORY:  system
      ARCH:  i386
   VERSION:  11.10.0,REV=2005.01.08.01.09
   BASEDIR:  /
    VENDOR:  Sun Microsystems, Inc.
      DESC:  GNU wget - a utility to retrieve files from the World Wide Web (root components) 1.12
    PSTAMP:  sfw10-patch-x20100616081054
  INSTDATE:  Dec 13 2012 23:00
   HOTLINE:  Please contact your local service provider
    STATUS:  completely installed
     FILES:        2 installed pathnames
                   1 shared pathnames
                   1 directories
                   1 executables
                   9 blocks used (approx)
```