# Command to download the package from internet in solaris

Tags: solaris

Can any one suggest a command to download the package from the interent in the solaris box?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to download the zip file from the internet to the solaris box using the terminal command

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/14584664/141978 from RaamEE:

> The wget command in Solaris 10 is somewhat hidden from sight.
>
> You can find it here
>
> `/usr/sfw/bin/wget`
>
> This was checked on s10u10

Then use `/usr/sfw/bin/wget <url>`

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell as you provide few information but `wget` is a common tool to retrieve things from the Internet.

```
wget http://server/package.zip
```

If a Solaris package, `pkgadd` also supports URLs:

```
pkgadd -d http://server/package.pkg
```

Answer (score 0):

I once needed to get `wget` installed on old remote Solaris 8 server (there is no `/usr/sfw/` on Solaris 8).

So, after some web surfing, I did the following:

1. Downloaded **wget-1.10.2-sol8-sparc-local.gz** from http://download.nust.na/pub3/solaris/sparc/5.8/ to my Windows machine (where I always have 7-Zip installed)
2. Extracted **wget-1.10.2-sol8-sparc-local.gz**
3. Uploaded resulting package **wget-1.10.2-sol8-sparc-local** into Solaris server
4. Under root user executed `pkgadd -d wget-1.10.2-sol8-sparc-local`

Right away you can start using it as `wget <URL>`.